# Text box and check box dependency in haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a form in htaml.haml (ruby on rails) that consists of a list of check boxes and two text boxes. These two text boxes are dependent on two check boxes. If a check box is clicked , corresponding text box should be editable, otherwise it should be non-editable. 
My form Looks like this

```
%script(src ="/app/assets/a.js")
%h1 Registration
%h2 User Information
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
     = form_for(@user) do |f|
       = f.label :cisco_email,'Cisco Email'
       = f.email_field :cisco_email
       = f.label :name, 'Current group'
       = f.text_field :current_group
       = f.label :name, 'Current work location,city'
       = f.text_field :work_city     
%h2 Area of Interests: check at least one box that apply, can select maximum of 2
.row
 .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
   = form_for(@user) do |f|
     = f.check_box :conflict_resolution
     = f.label :conflict_resolution, 'Conflict Resolution'
     = f.check_box :customer_know_how
     = f.label :customer_know_how, 'Customer Know How'
     = f.check_box :exec_acheive_results
     = f.label :exec_acheive_results, 'Executive to achieve results'
     = f.check_box :personal_branding
     = f.label :personal_branding, 'Personal Branding'
     = f.check_box :leading_change 
     = f.label :leading_change, 'Leading Change'
     = f.check_box :align_and_influence    
     = f.label :align_and_influence, 'Align and Influence'
     = f.check_box :managing_without_authority
     = f.label :managing_without_authority, 'Managing Without Authority'
     = f.check_box :win_win_negotiation
     = f.label :win_win_negotiation, 'Win-Win Negotiation'
     = f.check_box :career_exploration
     = f.label :career_exploration, 'Career Exploration'
     = f.check_box :effective_communication
     = f.label :effective_communication, 'Effective Communication'
     = f.check_box :think_out_box
     = f.label :think_out_box, 'Creative Thinking/Think Out Of the box'
     = f.check_box :tech_know
     = f.label :tech_know, 'Technical Know-How, List Areas'
     = f.text_field :other
     = f.label :other, 'Any Other'
     = f.check_box :other_areas
     = f.text_field :tech_areas
     = f.submit "Register Me", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I'm doing this in JavaScript file

```
$(document).on('click', '#user_tech_know', function (event) {
if (this.checked) {
$('#user_other').show();
} else {
$('#user_other').hide();
}
});
```

I am new to all this. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tech_know', function (event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#other').show();
  } else {
    $('#other').hide();
  }
});
```

**Caveat**

Use Firebug or view source to see the actual IDs of the fields in question and adjust code to match them.  So, for instance, if ID of what you want to show/hide is 'foo', replace '#other' above with '#foo' (# is jQuery for "this is an ID").

Comment: It's working but not for the first time. I mean when I check and un-check the check_box , it starts working .

Comment: Hmm not sure.  Where are you loading JS on your page?  I like to put my JS at the bottom of my page layout to ensure all of the HTML is loaded before I try to attach events to it.  Otherwise, can you update your OP with your updated code so we can all have a look?

Comment: I added the my complete code of new.html.haml and javasript code.

Comment: @Sainadh I suspect the issue is that you are loading the JS at the top of your page, before the elements to which you are attaching events have been defined.  If you move this to the bottom it may help.  Even better is to include your JS in your layout (after body) so that you do not need to do these includes on a case by case basis.  Better still is to use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) if you are using Rails 3.1 or later.